# 2 way data binding issue using IE 11 with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have recently built a feature on our web application that uses AngularJS and I am having some issues with IE 11 not properly `$apply()`ing data changes to the DOM. For some reason this only occurs sometimes and never occurs when I try to debug the problem which makes it seem like a timing issue.

Here is the function that gets called when the problem occurs.

```
$scope.createThrottling = function (sources) {
            MYAPP.modals.Throttling('New', sources, API, function () {
                $scope.isLoading = true;

                $scope.$apply();


                API.Migrations.getThrottles({ id: jQuery.getUrlVar('id') }, function (data) {
                    $scope.Throttles = data.Throttles;
                    $scope.isLoading = false;

                    // THE PROBLEM IS RIGHT HERE

                });


            });
        }
```

The comment above shows where the problem seems to be stemming from.  At this point in the execution of the code, Angular should automatically be checking for a change in `$scope.Throttling` and then make a change to the DOM accordingly, however, for some reason in IE 11, on the first visit to the page the binding is not occurring.

Subsequent refreshes of the page cause the binding to work however which seems very strange.  It is as if `$scope.$apply()` is needed after `API.Migrations.getThrottles` is finished, but I cannot do that because Angular throws a JS error saying that it is already digesting.

Some things to note:

1. This only happens in IE
2. This only happens on the first visit to a page per load of the browser (I can hit F5 and try the same exact thing and it will work)
3. Could this be occurring because my `API.Migrations.getThrottles` call is inside a callback function for the `MYAPP.modals.Throttling` module which is outside of Angular completely?
4. When I try to debug the JS function above, everything works just fine which makes it seem like a timing issue

Any help to finding out what is causing this bug would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Try moving the `$scope.$apply` call into the the getThrottles callback

Comment: That is what I tried. I mentioned above that doing so resulted in Angular throwing an error saying that it is already digesting

Comment: I tried using `jQuery.on('throttleComplete', ...` and `jQuery.trigger('throttleComplete')` to trigger the callback instead of actually using a callback and that did not help either

Comment: Did you delete `$scope.$apply` call from the `.Throttling` callback and only have it in the getThrottles callback

Comment: No let me try that I guess

Comment: That did not change anything except for now it does not show my spinner because `$scope.isLoading` was not being `$apply()`ed correctly.

Comment: I even tried adding `$timeout`s around everything in that function to see if it was a timing issue, but that did not seem to help. Still strange how it always works fine when I am debugging in console

Comment: your `isLoading=true` should be outside the callbacks, ie before the .Throttling call. what is calling createThrottling?

Comment: No, it is where it should be. `MYAPP.modals.Throttling` just dynamically adds a pop up modal to the DOM that the user uses to add settings to Throttling. After they hit Submit and the an API is called, the callback function is executed and that is when `getThrottles` gets called.

Comment: createThrottling is just called by an `ng-click` directive on a button

Comment: The biggest problem is I can't use debugging Watches or anything to figure out the problem because it always works when I inspect it.

Comment: Ok so this is going to sound crazy, but for some reason if I put `console.log($scope.Throttles)` inside getThrottles and I have my JS console open, then it works!!!!!! WTF!!!

Comment: Actually I don't even need console.log().. if I have the debugger open at all then it works... i am beyond confused

Answer (score 6):

for the reference, found the solution here: http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/AngularJS-caching-issue-for-Internet-Explorer

```
$httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
}
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT';
```

Comment: This answer is pretty much spot on.

Comment: Thanks a lot....i spend whole day to solve this issue and in last culprit was cache.

Answer (score 3):

I think I have found my problem!  I finally tried printing the data that is coming back from the server in the DOM without using the debugger and I realized that the API response is NOT giving me back new data! It is sending back cached data that is no longer valid which is why the objects are not showing up in the DOM. This also explains why using the debugger works because it forces each API call to not be cached!

I was able to fix this problem in my `$resource` by adding `{ _: Date.now() }` in my `params` object in my `$resource`. This appends `_=1234567890` to all GET calls for this `$resource` which forces IE to not cache