# Why does some AngularJS code work only when IE console is open?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have this problem regarding an AngularJS controller ([2 way data binding issue using IE 11 with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394608/2-way-data-binding-issue-using-ie-11-with-angularjs)) and I just realized that the problem does NOT occur whenever I have the debugging tools open in IE 11.

Does anyone know why this might occur and if there is a way to fix it?

Comment: are you using `console.log()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Probably if you change `console.log` to `$log`, see what happens

Comment: I took out console.log() completely since you need the console open to view it. Instead I just have 2 divs on my page that I update with the `JSON.stringify($scope.Throttles)` and it is still happening. For some reason the `$scope.Throttles` object is identical before and after my `$scope.Throttles = data.Throttles` assignment

Comment: I think I found out why this is happening.. see my answer on my original post

Comment: 5th bullet http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/dn265017(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check for IE and then apply. This worked for me:

```
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; // Internet Explorer 6-11

if(isIE){
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
    }
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';
}
```